# Android: Unable to stop foreground service

Tags: android, service

Simply, I want to upload files over the net using a service.

I have created a service with both: binding and `startService`. I create a foreground service that displays the progress.

The issue is, after the upload is complete, I call `stopForeground(true)` and then `stopSelf` but the notification is not removed and (probably) the service is not killed.

Code of the service class:

```
public class UploaderService extends Service {

    // ...

    public void finishUpload(File audioFile, File eventsData) {
        LogWrapper.d(TAG, "finishUpload");
        mUploadHelper.upload(audioFile, eventsData)
        // consider this just a callback:
                .subscribe(uuid -> {
                    // Log is printed but service is not stopped
                    LogWrapper.d(TAG, "finishUpload.subscribe");
                    stopForeground(true);
                    stopSelf();
                }, LogWrapper::fatalError);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = NotificationsManager.getDefaultBuilder(this)
                .setProgress(0, 0, true)
                .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TOPIC_NAME))
                .setContentTitle("Uploading data to server");
        // first creating a notification with uuid,
        // after POST /post call, post.uid will be used.
        startForeground(DEAFULT_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        LogWrapper.d(TAG, "onBind " + intent);
        return mUploaderBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        LogWrapper.d(TAG, "onUnbind " + intent);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TOPIC_NAME, mUploadHelper.getTopic().name);
        startService(intent);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mUploaderBinder = new UploaderBinder();
    }

    public class UploaderBinder extends Binder {
        public UploaderService getService() {
            return UploaderService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `stopSelf` instead

Comment: why do you `startService(intent);` inside `onUnbind` ?

Comment: To keep the service running. Even though the activity is finished I want the service to be alive; hence I made it a foreground service

Comment: so make it both "started" and "bound" one, more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) ^F `Binding to a Started Service`

Answer (score 0):

Though I could not find it in docs, the `startService` command should be called from outside the service i.e. from an Activity. I called it from my activity just before binding to it and it worked as expected.

I was probably experiencing an undefined behavior- the service was starting but not stopping. I wish someone could give me a better explanation of why that was happening, and that this indeed is the correct way to do stuff.

Great thanks to @pskink for pointing me in the right direction.